# Windows language pack vs. localised version

Tags: windows, testing, windows-7, localization

I want to test my software works on Windows regardless of language.  Is there a difference between a localised install Windows 7 and an install with the language changed by a language pack?  Is it enough just change language packs to confirm my software works or do I need to install a localised version?  In particular I want to be sure that the code page used by the API changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's equivalent, you are perfectly safe using a language pack. I'm a bit concerned about your comment regarding code pages though--Windows 7 natively runs in Unicode (Windows 95/98/ME did not and relied on code pages, but this has changed from Windows XP) and it seems unthinkable nowadays not to develop in Unicode, or are you doing something very specific that requires you to use non-Unicode encodings?

If that clarifies things, on Windows XP and beyond, all the ANSI versions of the APIs (ending with a A) simply wrap the Unicode APIs (ending with a W), doing conversion to Unicode and back to ANSI on the way out.

Comment: My problem was that the ODBC API seemed to work only in 8-bit character sets.  It turns out there is a unicode API, it's just undocumented.  It's nice to know that I can easily test different language settings.